# How to use XMLTask Search replace

Tags: regex, search, ant, replace, xmltask

I'm trying to search and replace using below code.

```
    <replaceregexp  flags="g">  
   <regexp pattern="location=&quot;(.*?)&quot;"/>
        <substitution expression="location=&quot;xsd/\1&quot;"/> 
    <fileset dir="${fmw.finalDir}/xsl" includes="*.xsl"/>
      </replaceregexp>
```

It is working fine. But i want to know is there any way i can perform similar thing using "xmltask"

Comment: Have you read the xmltask documentation?  It's got examples of how to do exactly this sort of thing.  It helps to know how XPath works so you can easily identify which node in the XML tree is going to get updated.

Answer (score 1):

With `xmltask` you need to express the location to be replaced with xpath, so it really is only practical if you can do that easily.

Assuming it's the case for you, you can indeed follow the example on the [XmlTask online documentation](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) and write e.g.

```
<xmltask todir="${fmw.finalDir}/xsl">
   <fileset dir="${fmw.finalDir}/xsl" includes="*.xsl"/>
   <replace path="A/B/C[@location=""]/@location" withText="xsd"/>
</xmltask>
```

Comment: I think it will replace @location/text() with "xsd", although earlier is is finding some pattern and prefixing it with "xsd/".

Comment: Example:- if i have "abc", it is earlier code is converting it into "xsd/abc"